# Is $\lim _{ x\to \infty }\:x\:=\:\lim _{ t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}$?

Tags: calculus

Is $\lim _{ x\to \infty }\:x\:=\:\lim _{ t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}$  ?

Comment: but $t$ tends from $\pm 0$ to zero

Comment: it is not the same

Comment: Yes?? This is a really weird statement but I suppose they are "equal" by substitution even though neither of them exist. So they are equal in the sense that they can be exchanged but they are not "equal" in magnitude since they are both go to $\infty$.

Comment: I'm asking exactly because I want to solve a question exchanging x and t.

Comment: First limit diverges, second one isn't defined. Thus no, they aren't the same.

Comment: "First limit diverges, second one isn't defined"  Huh?  *limits* don't diverge they either exist or dont. *sequences* diverge.  And both of these do.

Comment: They would be the same, if the limit on $t$ was right handed.

Comment: I think they are the "same" in the sense that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} = \infty$ and $\lim_{t\rightarrow; t> 0} \frac 1t = \infty$ are both true statements.  But technically speaking the equal sign in "$\lim a_x = k$" does not meant there is a number that is $\lim a_x$ and it is k.  It means the sequence a_x and k have a relation (and k is uniquely so).  and $\lim a_x = \infty$ means the sequence a_x has a specific behavior.  Of, course if $\lim a_x = k$ and $k$ is unique we can use the notation $\lim a_x$ to refer to the unique number satisfying the relation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the limit are not defined, therefore we cannot say that they are equal (Since both tend to infinity, and two infinities need not to be equal), By the way if the limit is finite ;
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = a=\lim_{t \to 0^{\color{red}+}} f\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big)  $$

And ; 
$$\lim_{x \to ~-\infty} f(x) = a = \lim_{t \to 0^{\color{red}-}} f\Big(\frac{1}{t}\Big)  $$

Where , $a \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

Technically, no.

But I think it is a fair allowance of notation abuse. (Provided you specify that $t > 0$.)

Technically speaking $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = q$ does not mean that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x)$ is a number that is equal to $q$.  It means that the function $f$, and the numbers $a$ and $q$ have a special relationship and that $q$ is unique in having this relationship with $f$ and $a$[$*$].

But, because $q$ is unique it is well-defined and consistent and meaningful to say we can denote the unique $q$ so that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = q$ as $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) $ a number as well.

Likewise $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = \infty$ can not be viewed as an equality statement because $\infty$ is not a valid value.  Instead it is the statement about the behavior of function $f$ with reqards to the number $a$.[$**$]  As $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow b} g(x) = \infty$ means $f$ and $g$ have the same behavior in regards to $a$ and $b$, I believe IMO that it is abusive but fair to say   $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow b} g(x) = \infty$ .

I would say that, although technically incorrect, it is fair to state that:

$\lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) =\lim_{x\rightarrow b} g(x) $

can be taken to mean:

$f$ and $g$ have the same behavior in regards to the values $a$ and $b$ respectively.  i) either they converge to the same value ii) they both diverge "to" either the same $\pm \infty$ or iii) they both do neither i nor ii.

It's abusive notation but it is consistent, well-defined, and unambiguous and thus, imo, acceptable.